# Include empty responses in form

Tags: html, node.js, forms, post

I am trying using HTML, Jquery, and Node.js to develop an online test for my students. Currently, when I submit the form, the server gets a json object (using body-parser) that includes only the fields that were answered. However, I also need to be able to see which ones were not answer. For example, if my student answers questions 1, 2, 3 but not 4, the server shows the following:

{Q1: a, Q2:b, Q3:c}

I want to get:
{Q1: a, Q2:b, Q3:c, Q4:''}

I tried looking online, however most posts explain how to get rid of the empty responses and not how to include them.

This is what I have right now

```html
<div id="FormContainer1" class="container">
      <form id="Form1" action="/Form1" method="POST">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="row">
                <label> 1.  </label>
                <label>A </labe> <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="A">
                <label>B </labe> <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="B">
                <label> C </labe> <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="C">
                <label> D </labe> <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="D">
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <label> 2.  </label>
                <label> A </labe> <input type="radio" name="Q2" value="A">
                <label> B </labe> <input type="radio" name="Q2" value="B">
                <label> C </labe> <input type="radio" name="Q2" value="C">
                <label> D </labe> <input type="radio" name="Q2" value="D">
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <label> 3.  </label>
                <label> A </labe> <input type="radio" name="Q3" value="A">
                <label> B </labe> <input type="radio" name="Q3" value="B">
                <label> C </labe> <input type="radio" name="Q3" value="C">
                <label> D </labe> <input type="radio" name="Q3" value="D">
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <label> 4.  </label>
                <label> A </labe> <input type="radio" name="Q4" value="A">
                <label> B </labe> <input type="radio" name="Q4" value="B">
                <label> C </labe> <input type="radio" name="Q4" value="C">
                <label> D </labe> <input type="radio" name="Q4" value="D">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

and in the server I have,

```
app.post('/Form1', urlencodedParser, function(request,response){ console.log(request.body); })
```

Comment: FYI, most of your closing `</label>` tags have a typo missing the last 'l'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a hidden radio button for each question that is marked as `checked`:

```
<input type="radio" name="Q4" value="" style="display: none;" checked>
```